# WP 4.4 upgrade custom post type cannot add new

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins

We have a custom plugin we have created for a customer, it simply configures a custom post type.

They upgraded to wp 4.4 today.  Now that custom post type is the only one that you cannot add a new post for.I can edit a custom post with out issue and I can add the standard posts and other custom post types created with a third party plugin.

I have uploaded the plugin to a clean install of 4.4 with a default theme and it still has the issue.

My custom post has the capabilities of 'post'.  All I get once logged in is "Submit for Review". If you fill out the form and click the "submit for review" button then you get the message "You are not allowed to edit this post."

Here is the custom post declaration:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/image.png', __FILE__ ),
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('')
);

register_post_type( 'new_post_type' , $args );
```

I have double checked the DB has the right primary keys and auto increment too.

I have even tried creating new users and I have installed plugins to check the role capabilities which all look fine.

Any thoughts on how to diagnose?

**Update**
I believe that the capabilities are correct. After changing core WordPress file to retrieve the post type via query string rather than the blank new post object it passes around the correct info appeared.

The problem seems to be when you click the add new button in the main navigation WordPress creates a blank post in the DB, this does not persist for some reason.  As a result I get a post id of 0 returned rather than the next incremented id I should have.

This means that when it tries to pull out the meta info for id 0 it does not have the post type it is returned as '', therefore when it tries to get the capabilities for '' it fails and puts the form into the simplest view "submit for review".

Comment: I would recommend to look at [4.4 changelog](https://codex.wordpress.org/Version_4.4) and make sure that your code isn't using anything deprecated or is using anything that changed. `register_post_type()` didn't change in 4.4, Im afraid problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for the help, after a lot of playing around with the WP core files and debugging what is wrong I have found that  $post->post_type returns nothing when creating a new post (wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php).  If I hardcode in the correct post type all works fine.  The hunt continues...

Comment: Make sure to declare `global $post;` before your code.

Comment: I think I maybe getting closer to the issue but not the fix.  When I go to create the new post the id is 0 where when I go to a different post to add it has a value of the next id.  Still searching.

Comment: Is `post` a custom cap? Try changing your cap to `edit_posts` and let's know if that works.

Comment: post is predefined capability from WP (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you?! Please accept and upvote if it was helpful

Answer (score 1):

**The problem**

There are two kinds of capabilities defiend in wordpress:

- meta capabilities (edit_post, read_post, and delete_post)
- primitive capabilities

for the **meta capabilities** to function correctly for your **custom post type**, you need to map them using `map_meta_cap` argument, while using `register_post_type`.

**The solution**

1. In your `register_post_type`, the `map_meta_cap` has a `null` default value. set it to be **true** for the post capabilities desired functionality.
2. Don't use the `capabilities` argument. If so, `map_meta_cap` would not function correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I originally used an inbuilt capability of 'post', to see if this was the issue I did try to use custom created capabilities where I used the map_meta_cap method as you suggested but it did not work.  I believe the issue is due to persisting the new post to the DB before it returns to my custom form. still digging :)

Comment: You did not follow the step I suggested in my answer. I didnt tell u to create custom capabilities. Please read more carefully

Answer (score 0):

Is the post content empty or null?  I had similar problem with inserting a new post that mainly used custom fields and not using post content.  I had excluded them from the array.  This worked up to 4.3, but 4.4 gave a "Could not update post in the database" wp_error object.  Adding contents cured the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help but the problem appear to not be related to capabilities, if I change the core WordPress files so that it pulls out the right post type (which appears to be the problem) the new post page looks as it should with a publish button, but because of the issue clicking the button does not work as the checks are else where too, so I am confident that the capabilities are correct.